# Why do I see a difference in file count between Nautilus and find?

Tags: nautilus, files, find

For a university project, I have to count all the files in a folder. I have used the command:

```
find ./dirName | wc -l
```

Although when I compare this to the file count provided by Nautilus it is considerably more. See the screenshot below:

[image]

./dirName is actually a directory of files from a repository (SVN/GIT) and I need to find out how many files make up the system.

Could anyone explain why these differences occur and maybe tell me which one is more reliable?

Comment: Try to minimize the set of files on which you see a difference on (less than 10 items), then post a full directory listing (`ls -al`) as well as what you see in your file manager. We'll then be able to see what this causes. Now it's just guessing.

Comment: *"a directory of files from a repository (SVN/GIT)"* That is very relevant information. Do you want the real file system based file count or the one reporting from your Version Control System? Git uses tricks under water, like hard links and hidden dot-files. You can expect a large difference indeed, depending the differences between branches.

Comment: VCS? I want to know how many files, excluding directories are within the set of files downloaded from the repo. It is a git repository so you're probably right. Is there a way of counting the total number of files in the repository?

Comment: That's a totally different question if you would ask me. Include the VCS you're using. For Git I'll be glad to answer that. But it's here already: [How to get a count of all the files in a git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468970/how-to-get-a-count-of-all-the-files-in-a-git-repository). **Please include these relevant details from the beginning, it's a different question.**

Comment: That was just to get more help with my project. My main question was why there was a difference between the two numbers, which you answered very well. I very much appreciate your help. Hope I haven't n00bed too much. :)

Comment: No problem. Just make it a good practice to add al these relevant details to your question next time. Anyway, I've added a basic Git example to my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Nautilus doesn't count hidden files.

<sup>Files and directories starting with a dot (`.`) are hidden in Linux.</sup>

Steps to reproduce:

```
mkdir somedir && cd somedir
touch .hidden .hidden2 regular regular2      # 4 files, 2 hidden
find . | wc -l                               # outputs 5 (4 files + dir itself)
```

Nautilus reports: *Contents: 2 items, totalling 0 bytes*

#### Using Git

Here's a quick demonstration on the amount of files for the metadata used in Git, all in the `.git` directory.

```
git init myrepo                              # Initialized [...] in myrepo/.git/
cd myrepo/
find . | wc -l                               # outputs 23! for an empty repository
tree -a                                      # outputs 10 directories, 12 files

echo "have to add something for git ls-tree" > somefile
git add somefile && git commit -m "Initial commit"
find . | wc -l                               # outputs 38 (!)
git ls-tree -r HEAD | wc -l                  # outputs 1
```

And also Nautilus reports 1 there.

#### My suggestion: use `tree`

As Gilles pointed out in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/246353/88802), using `find` and piping it to `wc` isn't overly reliable if the file names contain special characters.

It seems that `tree` is capable of doing this right:

```
tree -a
.
├── dir
│   └── regular3
├── dir2
├── .hidden
├── .hidden2
├── regular
└── regular2

2 directories, 5 files
```

Comment: so by default are files with . prefix automatically hidden?

Comment: @D4nC00per Yes, all files/directories you start with dot (`.`) are hidden ones. In Nautilus you'll need `Ctrl`+`H` I believe, in listings using `ls` you'll need `-a` to show all files including hidden ones.

Comment: Using `tree -a ./dirName` output 1180. Which is a different number again. I added further detail to the question. The folder contains folders such as .htaccess as well as .gitignore files. So I'm unsure as to count the "hidden" files or not as some are not hidden but hidden due to their filename by ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, the count from tree is lower due to unreliabilities removed by using tree instead of find piped through wc

Answer (score 1):

There could be file names with newlines in them. Highly inadvisable, but technically possible. This may be what your exercise was about.

One way to reliably count the files under a directory is to make `find` print something that can be counted reliably, i.e. with one item per file.

> find ./dirName -printf a | wc -c

Keep in mind that `find` includes `dirName` itself, and recurses into subdirectories.

If you only want the files inside `dirName`, without recursing, let the shell count them:

```
GLOBIGNORE=.:..
set -- *
echo $#
```

Comment: Nautilus also recurses into subdirectories with this file count. In that sense it's just a 1-off. You're right about the newlines. Counting by parsing the output to `wc` isn't really reliable.

Comment: Is the bottom set of code terminal commands or a shell script?

Comment: @D4nC00per Either. Run it in bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the output of `find`:

```
find somewhere | less
```

You'll see that `find` by default outputs any kind of file, without making distinctions based on the type or on the name. Nautilus instead does not count the starting directory (`somewhere` in the example) or files that it would not show when browsing.

To solve the issue, use the `-type` option of find:

```
find somewhere -type f | wc -l
find somewhere ! -type d | wc -l
```

The first line will look for all regular files. The second all the non-directory items (i.e. regular files, block devices, UNIX sockets, and so on). See `man find` for more information.

You might be probably interested in reading about `-H`, `-L` and `-P`, which control how `find` should handle symlinks (and therefore how symlinks influence the counts).