# Explain difference in non-hidden file count when using Nautilus vs. using other tools such as tree and how to independently calculate former count?

Tags: nautilus, files, directory, hidden-files, tree

I recently have been backing up my files from a laptop and as part of that have opted to move a folder that at first seemed to be of size 107.6 GB from one hard drive to another. As I was copying, I noticed that a dialog box showed up saying there are far more files than I thought there were -- about 275,000 as opposed to about 160,000. Later, I realized that this has to do with dot files (i.e. hidden files). I wanted to know that when I finished copying that the size and number of files for source and destination matched. Well, I was able to use Nautilus folder dialogs to show that the non-hidden item counts and non-hidden item sizes for source and for destination were the same.

However, I would like to figure out how to arrive at those non-hidden item absolute numbers independently.

My questions are: (1) is there a conceptual explanation for a discrepancy between non-hidden item counts from Nautilus and from e.g. `tree`; and (2) how do we use existing tools other than Nautilus to get the results for non-hidden item count given by Nautilus?

---

### All (including hidden) items

I have tried `tree -a` inside the directory we care about, which gives:
`28949 directories, 246973 files`

This means `tree -a` gives **275,922 items total**.

Nautilus gives **275,923 items total**, assuming I have toggled on the "show hidden files" option for Nautilus; this is a match, since it is okay for us to add one to the result from `tree -a`.

### All non-hidden items

I have tried `tree` inside the directory we care about, which gives:
`14860 directories, 146703 files`

This means `tree` gives **161,563 non-hidden items total**.

Nautilus gives **160,829 non-hidden items total**, assuming I have toggled off the "show hidden files" option for Nautilus; also, even after adding one to the result from `tree`, the two counts from `tree` and Nautilus are slightly different.

---

I understand that Nautilus behaves (when "show hidden files" is off) by excluding dot-folders and dot-files and any (possibly non-dot folder or file) items that are recursively in some dot-folder. For small examples that I have crafted, results from `tree` and from Nautilus seem to match up.

Again, How do I explain the discrepancy for non-hidden item counts? It is worth noting that I am interested in recursive counts. Also, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the file system that the files are at is NTFS. I would provide the experimental data that I am using, but it is not so convenient to pull out non-sensitive data and simultaneously preserve this discrepancy for non-hidden item count.

Also, I have come across another AskUbuntu post that touches on Nautilus and `tree`, but it doesn't explain why there is a discrepancy when we avoid using the `-a` option:
[Why do I see a difference in file count between Nautilus and find?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246351/why-do-i-see-a-difference-in-file-count-between-nautilus-and-find)

---

Here are some pictures that, admittedly, do not really add any new details.

(I have temporarily named the folder in question "A".)

1. All (including hidden) items via Nautilus:
   [image]
2. All non-hidden items via Nautilus:
   [image]
3. All (including hidden) items via `tree -a`:
   [image]
4. All non-hidden items via `tree`:
   [image]

---

Again, if there is some other way besides using `tree` to count non-hidden files recursively in current folder and in subfolders s.t. we match up with Nautilus again, that would also be appreciated.

It seems that some approaches that use `find` or `ls` may be susceptible to special characters in folder or file names (e.g. new line). The previously provided AskUbuntu post is relevant for this detail. Also, here is a Unix StackExchange post with a response that mentions a `find`-based approach s.t. regular files in hidden folders are specifically are considered hidden as well in a count (just as we assume Nautilus and `tree` do), but the numbers don't match up perfectly, still:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18227/how-to-recursively-list-all-hidden-files-and-directories

The response that we mention is here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18228

---

Thanks,
Brian

---

Edit: The hard drive that these documents are stored on is a freshly formatted drive. The operating system is a freshly installed instance of Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. As far as I know, I do not have any extra processes interacting with the directory that I would like to measure number of non-hidden items for. Again, by non-hidden item, I mean an item that is not recursively in some dot-folder, assuming the main directory is not hidden. Again, is there a good explanation for why I get different results for Nautilus and for e.g. tree when counting non-hidden documents in a folder and is there a way to independently calculate the non-hidden item counts given by Nautilus?

Comment: Have you programs that run in or use that directory which create and remove temporary flies repeatedly ? If you add up the numbers in the first case (including hidden) the numbers are exactly the same. But they differ dramatically in the second case.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi: I have added a paragraph to the question; in short, no, I have no reason to believe I am writing to the folder in question.

Comment: @K7AAY: I have added the detail to the question; I attempted to not add comments, but ultimately I gave in given that I would like that the two of you commenters be notified. (I have waited around four days before doing this. Hopefully, I am not misunderstanding etiquette guidelines too much.) In short, I am using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.